# How to return JSON with libcurl.net (C#)?

Tags: c#, json, curl

I am trying to use libcurl.net to connect to a server and return the json from it. But instead of returning the JSON, it returns "CURLE_OK". Heres my code:

```
Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32);
Easy easy = new Easy();
var agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)";
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, string.Format("http://vikinglogue.com/api/get_posts/?page={0}", currentPage));
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_USERAGENT, agent);
easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, 1);
var responce = easy.Perform();
MessageBox.Show(responce.ToString());
easy.Cleanup();
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Please don't suggest an answer using WebClient, because, I can't use it (not by choice). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably expecting `CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT` to act like PHP's `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`. It doesn't, as the former is documented as *"tells the library to use ASCII mode for ftp transfers"*, which is totally irrelevant in this case as it's an HTTP request.

See the [EasyGet](http://libcurl-net.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/libcurl-net/libcurlnet/samples/EasyGet.cs?view=markup) sample, you need to pass a callback to a write function:

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    try {
        Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

        Easy easy = new Easy();
        Easy.WriteFunction wf = new Easy.WriteFunction(OnWriteData);

        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, args[0]);
        easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf);
        easy.Perform();
        easy.Cleanup();

        Curl.GlobalCleanup();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

public static Int32 OnWriteData(Byte[] buf, Int32 size, Int32 nmemb,
    Object extraData)
{
    Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf));
    return size * nmemb;
}
```